# Apache Kafka IO errors

Tags: scala, docker, apache-kafka

I have a very basic Kafka installation, just for testing. Now I'm trying to send some data to a topic from console:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --sync --broker-list 192.168.59.103:9092,192.168.59.103:9093,192.168.59.103:9094
test
test2
test3
[2015-02-16 06:19:37,156] WARN Failed to send producer request with correlation id 12 to broker 1 with data for partitions [test,0] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(SocketChannel.java:493)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferSend.writeTo(BoundedByteBufferSend.scala:56)
    at kafka.network.Send$class.writeCompletely(Transmission.scala:75)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferSend.writeCompletely(BoundedByteBufferSend.scala:26)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    ....
test4
test5
```

I'm getting such exceptions for about 30% of my message. Does it mean that something wrong with my configuration?

Why I'm getting it for only 1/3 of tries? Is it related somehow to the fact that I have 3 Kafka servers, and maybe one of the is down (btw, I'm executing this commands for same VM where Broker 1 is running)

Also, this is what I see in logs of this broker:

```
ERROR Error on broker 1 while processing LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 16 received from controller 1 epoch 4 for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:874)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:74)
```

Not sure what it means. Is it possible that Kafka got a corrupted index file and throws such errors because of that? Topic "test" was created just few minutes ago, btw, and I didn't restart anything.

I found that I can dump index to console, but it doesn't work too:

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /kafka-logs/test-0/00000000000000000000.index --deep-iteration
Dumping /kafka-logs/test-0/00000000000000000000.index
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:874)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:74)
```

Any ideas?

Kafka 0.8.2.0, Scala 2.11

UPDATE I seems to be a Docker incompatibility, more concrete incompatibility with docker shared volumes. Because if I put log data into local docker filesystem everything works fine. So looking for advice what configuration changes (docker/kafka/java/etc) I can make to make it working with shared volume.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problems, it appeared a disk full. That'll also explain why you only get it on 1/3th of the messages.

Comment: I'm sure I had free diskspace, more than 100gb free. That was run on developer machine, in docker. It reproducible, btw, with docker. works fine if I use internal docker vm disk, but fails for disk mounted from host machine. 
Btw, thanks for idea, I'll investigate it, maybe mounted disk provides incorrect information about free space, or something like this

Comment: I'm not really experienced with Docker, but I heard it had some problems with OS X and file mounts. 

Thanks for the update.